# Login as SYSTEM into SAP HANA trial instance

Tags: hana, hana-studio

Is there any way to login in HANA's trial instance as SYSTEM user? If so, what is the password?

I'm only able to login as the default user, but I need more privileges in order to perform certain operations.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to the HCP trial instance. SYSTEM user is not accessible in HCP, trial or paid account.
The paid accounts get you a dedicated instance where your account gets admin access and you can do most things that system account can.

What kind of privileges are missing in the trial environment?

Comment: I'm trying to import a project into my HANA trial instace, but I get the following error:
`SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: Not authorized`. Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429497/import-project-into-hana-trial-instance